# Why are equal signs used to substitute an English hyphen?

Tags: grammar, orthography

I was reading an article about Idlib and the groups that were there on Wikipedia, and hovered to the language setting to gloss at the title translations. For Japanese, I saw something unusual in its format. For example, the rendering of the name of one of those groups is 「タハリール・アル＝シャーム」instead of the usual 「タハリール・アル・シャーム」. I also saw this in manga character names such as「キルシュ＝ワイミー」. Is using the equals sign in place of nakaguro common and is it acceptable? If so, is it solely at the author's discretion?

Comment: I assume this is to disambiguate against 長音符 ー although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically speaking, this character should be `゠` (U+30A0 KATAKANA-HIRAGANA DOUBLE HYPHEN), not `＝` (U+FF1D FULLWIDTH EQUALS SIGN), and is indeed used to avoid confusion with 長音符: `ー` (U+30FC KATAKANA-HIRAGANA PROLONGED SOUND MARK).

From the [Double hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hyphen) Wikipedia page:

> In Japanese, the double hyphen (ダブルハイフン *daburu haifun*) in rare cases
>   replaces an English en dash or hyphen when writing foreign words in
>   katakana due to their potential confusion with the prolonged sound
>   mark (ー). It may be used to separate a person's given and family
>   names, such as transcribing the name of Galileo Galilei as:
>   ガリレオ＝ガリレイ. The middle dot (・) is however much more commonly used
>   for these purposes. (For foreign names that include both spaces and
>   hyphens, both the middle dot and double hyphen may appear together as
>   in Catherine Zeta-Jones: キャサリン・ゼタ゠ジョーンズ.) The double hyphen is part of
>   the JIS X 0213 standard, but is not included in more commonly used
>   character encodings, such as Shift-JIS and EUC-JP. For this reason,
>   the equals sign is frequently used in its place.